# PHP variable Syntax using _GET

Tags: php, string, syntax-error, concatenation

I have a redirectURL that currently redirects to a default page and works great

```
  $WA_redirectURL = "mypage.php";
```

I want to insert a _GET value that is available but am getting a syntax error.  Here is what I am trying.  I thought the periods would allow me to get the value into the URL?

```
  $WA_redirectURL = "mypage.php?EmpNumber=". echo $_GET['EmpNumber'] .";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't use `echo` when concatenating strings:

```
$WA_redirectURL = "mypage.php?EmpNumber=". echo $_GET['EmpNumber'] .";
```

should be:

```
$WA_redirectURL = "mypage.php?EmpNumber=". $_GET['EmpNumber'];
```

(The last quote is also an error).

Comment: Thanks John, second " was the problem like you said!

Answer (score 1):

You use echo to send text to the user.

If you want to join strings together use the period to join things.

For example:

```
echo "hello"; // this will print hello to the screen

$testing = "hello "."world!";

echo $testing; // this will print hello world! to the screen.
```